# How to enumerate all drop-down options in an html form using Burp Suit Intruder

Tags: burp-suite

In my app there is a form with a `<select>` element which has several `<options>` to choose from. I want to get all the responses that correspond to each option available in the form. The best method I came up with is to copy/paste the html text from the page into a text file and then manually create a newline delimited list which I import and use as a Runtime file in my payload. Is there an easier way to do this? Maybe right-click the `<select>` element and "Create payload"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't possible in core Burp but I have coded you an extension to do this. You can download it [here](https://github.com/pajswigger/select-payload-generator/releases/download/1.0/select-payload-generator.jar)

This version takes quite a basic approach, using regular expressions to parse the HTML. I'm sure it could be greatly improved.

Comment: Wow thanks! This is exactly what I needed. For anybody looking to use this, all you do is..
1. Load the extension using Extender
2. Right click a <select> element in any html viewer in Target/Repeater/Intruder etc. and select "Create payload from options"
3. In Intruder under Payloads choose "Extension-Generated" in Payload type 
4. Click Select generator ... and choose "Select Payload" for the Extension generator payload then click OK
5. Click Start attack

Comment: Glad you like it @Chancelot !